# How do i get a variable from an inline js script in html and put it into an external .js file?

Tags: javascript

I want to put a variable i got through an inline script in an: index.ejs file. This is the code i have got in that is:

```
$(function(){ 

 var finalpoints = points;
 var finalcosts = costammount;
 finaldata = [finalpoints,finalcosts];
});
```

and the code i have in the external file is:

```
(function( detail, $, undefined, index) {
    'use strict';
    var fd= finaldata;
})(fd, jQuery);
```

and nothing happens.. it does error:

```
ReferenceError: fd is not defined
at /app/index.js:95:4
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/rbd/pnpm-volume/9dc75d7a-5227-48ce-8d3d-268791bd5521/node_modules/.registry.npmjs.org/express/4.17.1/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at next (/rbd/pnpm-volume/9dc75d7a-5227-48ce-8d3d-268791bd5521/node_modules/.registry.npmjs.org/express/4.17.1/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (/rbd/pnpm-volume/9dc75d7a-5227-48ce-8d3d-268791bd5521/node_modules/.registry.npmjs.org/express/4.17.1/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/rbd/pnpm-volume/9dc75d7a-5227-48ce-8d3d-268791bd5521/node_modules/.registry.npmjs.org/express/4.17.1/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at /rbd/pnpm-volume/9dc75d7a-5227-48ce-8d3d-268791bd5521/node_modules/.registry.npmjs.org/express/4.17.1/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:281:22
    at Function.process_params (/rbd/pnpm-volume/9dc75d7a-5227-48ce-8d3d-268791bd5521/node_modules/.registry.npmjs.org/express/4.17.1/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
    at next (/rbd/pnpm-volume/9dc75d7a-5227-48ce-8d3d-268791bd5521/node_modules/.registry.npmjs.org/express/4.17.1/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
    at serveStatic (/rbd/pnpm-volume/9dc75d7a-5227-48ce-8d3d-268791bd5521/node_modules/.registry.npmjs.org/serve-static/1.14.1/node_modules/serve-static/index.js:75:16)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/rbd/pnpm-volume/9dc75d7a-5227-48ce-8d3d-268791bd5521/node_modules/.registry.npmjs.org/express/4.17.1/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using global variable, i.e., declare it before closure, in global scope. It's not a "clean" solution, but easiest one to try and see if rest of the code works OK.

```
var globalData = {
  finalpoints: 0,
  finalcosts: 0
};

$(function(){ 
 globalData.finalpoints = points;
 globalData.finalcosts = costammount;
});
```

and then:

```
(function( detail, $, undefined, index) {
    'use strict';
    var fd= globalData;
})(fd, jQuery);
```

You can also declare some global function, and call it from external files, instead of accessing variables directly, to get the values you need. That way you can return an object with data and add/remove more data to it when needed.

```
function getFinalData() {
  return [globalData.finalpoints, globalData.finalcosts];
}
```

or simply don't wrap inlined data and don't use global variable:

```
function getFinalData() {
  var finalpoints = points;
  var finalcosts = costammount;
  return [finalpoints, finalcosts];
}
```

and then:

```
(function( detail, $, undefined, index) {
    'use strict';
    var fd= getFinalData();
})(fd, jQuery);
```

After that you may try some message passing solutions like custom events (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events), or some global data store library, or even https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage (or sessionStorage), etc... depending on what scope external file is run in and/or how often data has to be passed.

Keep in mind that inlined code has to be run before the one from external file, i.e., inline it before including other scripts.

Comment: hey i tried all your methods and when i ran it it errored:                         ReferenceError: fd is not defined
    at /app/index.js:96:4

Comment: can you update your question with both html and external js, and how you connect to that external js? some basic setup to debug?